# WeakReference to String and String constants

Tags: java, weak-references

I have come across this example from wikipedia regarding weak reference:

```
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

public class ReferenceTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

            WeakReference r = new WeakReference(new String("I'm here"));
            WeakReference sr = new WeakReference("I'm here");
            System.out.println("before gc: r=" + r.get() + ", static=" + sr.get());
            System.gc();
            Thread.sleep(100);

            // only r.get() becomes null
            System.out.println("after gc: r=" + r.get() + ", static=" + sr.get());

        }
}
```

I don't understand in this scenario why only r.get() returns null but not the sr.get(). Can someone let me know the reason?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the literal `"I'm here"` is a compile time constant string and as such gets placed in the constant string pool, which (up until java 7) was never garbage collected. that means `sr` points to an object that will never be garbage collected.
`r`, on the other hand, points to a copy of that string, which is not in any const pool and so is eligible for collection.

see the [documentation for String.intern()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) for some more details on this string pool

Answer (score 0):

If this reference object has been cleared, either by the program or by the garbage collector, then this method returns null.

[very well explained here](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references)